# Vim capture group has an unwanted space

Tags: regex, vim

The context is that I am copy pasting React props definition into the function arguments, so that I don't have to type the variable names one by one:

```
// Select these 3 lines with V3j  
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  formName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  formPurpose: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  formPlaceholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

<MyComponent
  // Past here with the output below  <-----------  expeted output
  formName={formName}
  formPurpose={formPurpose}
  formPlaceholder={formPlaceholder}
/>
```

To remove the `: PropTypes.string.isRequired` and change it to `={variableNameHere}` I'm using the following Vim regex:

```
:'<,'>s/\(.*\)\zs:.*/={\1}/g
```

This should capture the variable name, remove everything after `:` and put the capture inside the curly brackets on `={}`.

The result is the following:

```
formName={  formName}
formPurpose={  formPurpose}
formPlaceholder={  formPlaceholder}
```

There's an unwanted space after `{` and I can't figure out what is that space in the regex. Any ideas?

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: Updated the question to make it clear what's the expected output

Comment: you may have a whitespace at the beginning of the line maybe replace `.*` with `\w*` may help? Can not reproduce that without the whitespace. If you can run vim without your plugins/conf (vim -u NONE) and try again

Comment: Seems like I had whitespaces, silly me. I updated the question to include the whitespaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
:'<,'>s/[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)\zs:.*/={\1}/g
```

The spaces you get are the leading spaces before your expression.

Comment: Can also use `\s` instead of `[[:blank:]]` here. It is a bit easier to type